# how can i make a specific animation on hover

Tags: css, sass

Can somebody tell me how can i do this animation on hover please ?

[image]

Here some CSS code :
the effect is like a shake but it's not like the GIF
the effect is like a shake but it's not like the GIF
the effect is like a shake but it's not like the GIF
the effect is like a shake but it's not like the GIF
the effect is like a shake but it's not like the GIF

https://codepen.io/meruem92/pen/ZEoPWgP

```css
.carousel-item {
  transition: font-size 1s;

  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: #fff;

  &:before,
  &:after {
    display: block;
    content: attr(data-glitch);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  &:after {
    color: #fff;
    z-index: -2;
  }
  &:before {
    color: #ffffff69;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  &:hover {
    font-size: 35px !important;
    &:before {
      animation: glitch 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) both 2;
    }
    &:after {
      animation: glitch 0.8s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94) reverse both 2;
    }
  }

  @keyframes glitch {
    0% { transform: translate(0); }
    20% { transform: translate(-5px, 5px); }
    40% {  transform: translate(-5px, -5px); }
    60% { transform: translate(5px, 5px);  }
    80% { transform: translate(5px, -5px);  }
    to { transform: translate(0);  }
  }
}
```

```html
    <p data-glitch="Explore" class="carousel-item"> lorem ipsum </p>
```

Comment: Please show us enough code for us to be able to answer this sensibly. Put the code you have tried so far direct into your question and explain in what way it isn't working as you require. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i updated the post, sorry for the repeated text, i couldn't validate it without this.

Comment: Please give us a runnable snippet. Please don’t fill out the text with repeated useless stuff. Use the fact that you are required to put in more text to actually help us help you by describing in what way you are not getting the effect you want.

Answer (score -1):

You will want to use the CSS pseudo :hover to make the animation work. Something like this:

```
div {
    font-size:16px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
div:hover {
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: i updated the post, sorry for the repeated text, i couldn't validate it without this.

Comment: @burkay i don't know, but this code just make a text more bigger

Comment: @MeryemACHEMLAL, https://animista.net/ or https://webcode.tools/generators/css/keyframe-animation may help writing the animation you want.